# How to develop unique GUI's in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

All programs that I develop utilize the default Windows Design template:
[image]

Besides from changing the colors of the form, basically every program I write has this layout. I'm wondering how people create more custom GUI's. I tried looking it up on google but I clearly don't know how to phrase it to search. When I say custom GUI's I mean things like:
[image]

I assume it comes down to customizing what loads, but I don't know where to look, or what to research.

Comment: Those controls in your example looks like DevExpress' skins and controls. I've used them for a winforms project, they look good. Black skin @ http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/i/skins/Black.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should check out WPF. it frees you from the standard windows form

Comment: WPF is pretty much the way to go for any new GUI work. WinForms is still supported, but it's not being extended, so to get the full benefit from the Windows Aero/Metro renderers you need to take advantage of what WPF has to offer.

Answer (score 7):

Your app 10 years from now:

[image]

Easily implemented in Winforms btw.  FormBorderStyle is None, the Region and BackgroundImage properties and some judicious OnPaint() code.

Comment: I completely agree. Many applications that use styling/skins actually have no need to. By using styling, developers also take the risk of poor performance over remote control software like RDP as they are graphics-intensive, or on older computers (skinning requires code and any code takes time to run). It also forces an higher learning curve on the end-user because your application looks different from the majority of them. In my opinion, software is not about fashion, but about getting the job done in the most efficient way both in terms of user productivity and performance.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention accessibility issues for disabled/visually impaired people... Well, it is not really developers' fault... Microsoft did put a lot of efforts at this back in the 90s/2000s but are now showing the bad example with non-standard and not heavily customizable UIs like those of the Office 2010 suite, imho.

Comment: @KharlosDominguez While I agree with the first part of what you said the part where you say software is not about fashion etc is exactly what gives OSX that extra edge over Windows. They make the software work, but they also spend a lot of time crafting the user experience and visuals. I think MS has closed that gap recently, but in conclusion I think they are both important, obviously if you can only choose one then you choose "it works well" over "it's pretty".

Comment: ERGH! I'm cringing

Answer (score 4):

try one of the following:

- [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/)
- [Elegant UI](http://www.prof-uis.com/elegant-ribbon/net-winforms-controls.aspx)
- [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Metro Framework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/). It is free, open source and famous one. I have recently used it and found it is very attractive. You can also find screenshots of the gui and code examples on the above mention link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it really *must* be a native desktop app then use WPF..  otherwise, with the rise of HTML5 and the mobile device, i can't see any reason *not* to build cross-platform web apps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "how".

Answer (score 0):

1. For WinForms, most of the custom controls can be created by overriding the OnPaint method of a control and performing your own custom painting.
2. You could also use WPF, and create your own themes and styles
3. Or you could download a 3rd-party control such as the ones mentioned by johntotetwoo.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use WPF instead, if it is possible for you to use Expression Blend, i highly suggest using Expression Blend for Designing UI(s), Storyboards(animations) and customizing UI(s) then you feel like you are walking in heaven :)

Then i suggest you to use templates or themes for WPF. Like zune theme, and if you are interested in Microsoft Office themes, the good news for you is there is an overflowing of themes like this, just google it!

but is suggest you to design your own controls if you are able to use Blend except for those situations that you see you can not do this really.