# Rich User Interface Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, effects

I am a noob `C++` Programmer.
I want to develop `GUI` applications. I am using Visual Studio 2010. 
Normally, `Visual Studio` Projects begin with the old style interface with a frame with a menu in it. But I want to build an application with more rich Graphical elements. Just like the windows 8 start screen.. or the Visual studio start page. Please teach me how to do those fancy effects.

**Edit:** I don't like to use `flash` or <strike>`JavaFX`</strike> `Java` because they need additional programs to be installed before using.

Comment: You can create [self-contained JavaFX applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) which do not need additional programs to be installed before using - not saying you should in your case and you can't do it in Visual Studio anyway, just correcting a statement in your edit.

Comment: Thank you jewelsea. But there still exists some barriers. The size  of the application is large, because they include a private version of JRE. Also Java programs are much slower than C or C++.

Comment: but Java will run anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically you have not much options here. Regarding to your choice (MS Visual Studio) they are:

- **MFC/C++** - not convinient at all, I can say it's a small pain in the ass. But a lot of program were written exactly with a help of MFC library. It's a canonical way :)
- **Windows Forms/C++** - actually it's not usial C++, but C++/CLI. Not so much different, but has a [few](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6882/A-first-look-at-C-CLI) [things](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8074/Hello-C-CLI-Part-1) to note. You can take a look at [C++/CLI Cheat Sheet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320761/Cplusplus-CLI-Cheat-Sheet) for example. Not usial, but, hey, you can use Windows Forms!
- **Windows Forms/C#** - as for me, this combination is almost perfect. Nothing to add.
- **WPF/C#** - even much more interesting. Any control can be modified in any way, but you have to know a lot of tricks and howtos to make all things work. In that case I highly suggest to use [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). Anyway, you can find a lot of cool stuff for WPF (I even made once a mini-SCADA with a bunch of UI elements related to industrial stuff (valve, pumps, etc.)). Do not forget, you can do **animation** as well. It is pretty easy.
- **Qt addon for MSVS/C++** - the last but not the least option. All UI you make in Qt Quick - GUI IDE. Also you have a greatiest slot/signal interaction model (which was improved in Qt5.0).

My choise now is definitely Qt. It's crossplatform, btw.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, well organized answer. Would you please clear one more doubt for me.. From wikipedia, I got a bad impression about .NET. They say memory management for large applications are a mess. That's why I left Java. They need Java runtime to be installed and they are interpreted run-time. So what about C. Is there any options in Visual Studio for Developing a GUI C Application just like Windows Forms(drag and design)?

Comment: Hi, farseen. Under 'Developing a GUI C Application' you mean C# as well as C++ I guess? If so, the asnwer on your question is yes. If you use MFC - you can drag and drop any control. If you would prefer WPF - you can drap and drop there too. But it is all about standart and default components (I must say, MFC has not so much components to deal with). If you want your UI be more richer, you have to do some UI programming.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ you can create a WinForms (Windows Forms) project.

But nowadays WPF is preferred over WinForms, and WPF is usually used from C# or VB.NET. I'm not sure if it's possible to use from C++, but if so it would have poor support. C# is pretty easy to learn if you already know C++.

If you want to create Windows Store apps in Windows 8, you can also use C++/CX, but that requires VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

So you really want to make flashy things like these, eh? Well, you can make a Windows Store app, but like previously mentioned it requires Visual Studio 2012.

Take a look at this question too: [How to develop unique GUI's in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169876/how-to-develop-unique-guis-in-visual-studio)

[image: Sexy stuff...]

Answer (score 0):

You have several options of GUI from which you can choose wxWidgets, Qt, Ultimate++.

Answer (score 0):

or u can use Embarcadero C++ Developer ----> actually Firemonkey is so amazing check it out
[C++ Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder)